# Selenium FluentWait method failing to ignore NoSuchElement

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a web report page where I have to verify all the date fields in each page. I can get to each page and do the verification but my script gives an error at the FluentWait method

[image]

I have to get the dates of first page, verify it and then click the Next button if its enabled. If its not enabled I get out of the loop.

```
do {

......
.....
FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00"))));
    driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00")).click();


} while (driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00")).isEnabled());
```

But I get an error. Why is the NoSuchElement override not working? How can I exit from *ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable* gracefully?

Is there a better way to do this?

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (256df980-a068-474c-9469-2ff4e8e13b3e)] -> id: ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00]
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'PC-L-JOSU', ip: '172.26.70.109', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (256df980-a068-474c-9469-2ff4e8e13b3e)] -> id: ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00]
 org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
at com.stta.ReportsParkingTransactions.ReportsParkingTransactions.ReportParkingTransactions(ReportsParkingTransactions.java:414)
```

Thanks

EDIT

---

I tried without the expected conditions and see this error. What am I missing

[image]

**Someone please help!**.. :-)... I have googled this and looked everywhere posible and I'm stuck for the last few days !!!

Comment: is "ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00" stay the same always? I think it may be a dynamic id

Comment: No.. its not dynamic as it works every time and clicks the button as long as its enabled.. I am having this porblem only when the state changes to disabled

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is, you are not supposed to use `ExpectedConditions` with `FluentWait` at least you do not need to. According to the [doc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) the following should be enough

```
// Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
// for its presence once every 5 seconds.
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement reportViewer = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
  public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00"));
  }
});

reportViewer .click();
```

Comment: Can that be a syntax error like missing quote semi-colon?

Comment: No.. I had tried this initially too and when I got stuck with this error had tried to do the Expected Conditions..

Comment: @user3749141 I guess yo missed the import `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;`

Comment: Can you provide the full code block then including the `imports` I do not see that in my end

Comment: It doesn't allow me to post the full code as its apparently too much code for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'TimeoutException.class' in ignoring method which will ignore timeout exception as well. So test case will not fail for timeout exception.

EX: **.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, TimeoutException.class)**

Comment: I tried this and still get the same error "Timed out after 30 seconds" :-(

Comment: Try using either 'ignoreAll()' or 'ignoring(Exception.class)'.

Comment: No luck.. I still get the TimoutException... !!