# How to check for disabled state of element and then continue in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have this next button and the script keeps clicking the button until it gets to the last page. It should read and compare data in each page and then it should exit from the loop once the button is disabled. It reads data and does the comparison without problems when next button is in an enabled state, but when the next button is disabled the script doesn't read that page

This is the element

[image]

This is my code

```
do {
....
....

      if(driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00")).isDisplayed()) {

      driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00")).click();

        } else {

        }           
   } while(driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00")).isDisplayed());
```

The problem is that when the second page is reached, next the button becomes disabled and the While exits without reading the data in page 2.

How do I make sure that the page is read

1. When there is only 1 page of data(so next button will be disabled at the start itself)
2. When the last page is reached, (the next button goes to disabled state)

I had tried FluentWait but failed as described here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282178/selenium-fluentwait-method-failing-to-ignore-nosuchelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282178/selenium-fluentwait-method-failing-to-ignore-nosuchelement/%22here%22)

EDIT..added the HTML for disabled state of button

```
<td>
    <input id="ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl01_ctl00" type="image" 
style="border-style: none; height: 16px; width: 16px; border-width: 0px; cursor: default;"
 alt="Next Page" src="/xxxx Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=
0.0.30319.1&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.NextPageDisabled.gif" 
title="Next Page" disabled="disabled" name="ReportViewer1$ctl06$ctl00$Next$ctl01$ctl00">
```

EDIT again ---
The HTML when the button is enabled(There is no disabled attribute)

```
<input id="ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00" type="image" style="border-style: 
none; height: 16px; width: 16px; border-width: 0px;" alt="Next Page" 
src="/xxxxx/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.30319.
1&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.NextPage.gif"
 title="Next Page" name="ReportViewer1$ctl06$ctl00$Next$ctl00$ctl00">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`isEnabled()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled()) check instead of `isDisplayed()`.

Comment: When I do isEnabled()..... I never get out of the loop  Page 1, page 2, page 2, page 2... etc

Comment: @sunjose are you sure that the element `ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00` is getting disabled? can you share the HTML code of the page when the button is disabled? Thanks.

Comment: sorry I meant isEnabled.. just corrected my statement above... so doesn't make sense to me if the button looks like its disabled then how come isEnabled keeps finding the button

Comment: @sunjose hm, looks good. Can you try with `driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl00_ctl00")).getAttribute("disabled") != "disabled"` condition?

Comment: I have added the HTML for enabled state.. it doesn't have an "disabled" attribute... so this line would fail when the state is enabled.. I tried it and I get Page 1 twice and then endless page 2.. never gets out of the while statement