# Selenium Webdriver - how to check if attribute is missing and then proceed

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

The "disabled" attribute for the element is only present when the button is enabled. For a disabled state the attribute **disabled="disabled"** is not shown in the HTMl (the attribute itself and not the value)

How can I check for attribute and if its not there then proceed

I tried this

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button")).getAttr‌​ibute("disabled") != "disabled"
```

but when the button is in disabled state this line fails as there is no "disabled" attribute

HTML

```
<td>
<input id="ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl00_Next_ctl01_ctl00" type="image" 
style="border-style: none; height: 16px; width: 16px; border-width: 0px;     
cursor: default;" alt="Next Page" src="/xxxx Reserved.
ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=
0.0.30319.1&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.NextPageDisabled.gif" 
title="Next Page" disabled="disabled"
name="ReportViewer1$ctl06$ctl00$Next$ctl01$ctl00">
```

Comment: As simply you said when the button with 'id= button' is enabled then attribute disabled is present. 
When the button is disabled then attribute disabled is not present. 
so What exactly you are trying to achieve? Please simplify your question and add more HTML code snippet for it.

Comment: Please see this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308412/how-to-check-for-disabled-state-of-element-and-then-continue-in-selenium-webdriv

Comment: What if you tried driver.findElement(By.id("button")).getAttr‌​ibute("disabled") != null .

Comment: When I use the above I don't get an error but the While exits without reading the details of the page.. So a Do While loop doesn't do the trick.. anyway, if you answer with the above I can set your answer as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button")).getAttr‌​ibute("disabled") != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,

```
public boolean existsElement(By locator) {

    try {

        driver.findElement(locator);

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

if web element is present it will return `true` and if it is not present it will return `false`, depending upon flag value you can proceed.

```
By lctr = By.xpath("//*[@id='button'][@disabled='disabled']");

boolean flag = existsElement(lctr);
```